# $query combine nested constraints

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have the following query:

```
$query = $this->createQuery();
$constraint = [];
$constraint[] = $query->like('title', '%' . $searchTerm . '%');
$constraint[] = $query->like('description', '%' . $searchTerm . '%');
$query->matching($query->logicalOr($constraint));
```

This query works. Now I a have a new constraint, which I want do add with `locigalAnd`. How can I do this?

The new constraint is:

```
$constraint[] = $query->contains('categories', $myCategory);
```

How can I combine them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like to put it like that:

```
$q = $this->createQuery();

$titleOrDescriptionConstraints = $q->logicalOr(
  [
    $q->like('title', '%' . $searchTerm . '%'),
    $q->like('description', '%' . $searchTerm . '%'),
  ]
);

$constraints = $q->logicalAnd(
  [
    $titleOrDescriptionConstraints,
    $q->contains('categories', $myCategory),
  ]
);

$res = $q->matching($constraints);
```

But it's just a question of style.
If you like it more, you can of course coerce it in one expression.

Just remember that you can pass arrays of single expressions to the ->logicalAnd() and -Or() - functions and that you can nest them as deep as you want.